# debug an api response from a rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a front end guy having to debug a rails app and am a bit confused as to where exactly i should be looking in the source code to find the source of an error

Basically i have 3 tables

1. A user table (user id , username , avatarUrl)
2. A Stream table (stream id, stream name etc)
3. A Follow table (userid, streamid)

A user can only have 1 stream.

I'm sending the below api request from the front end to get a list of users following a particular stream

`/users/{id}/following` - retrieves the following list

I can see the controller acting for this as

```
  def following
    following = FollowEntry.where(user_id: @user.id)
    render json: following, scope: @user
  end
```

The api response i get is quite weird. Basically the json response looks like the below (assuming i'm user kunkka)

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "stream":{"id":1,"title":"Stream","slug":"bowie"},
  "user":{"id":2,"username":"kunkka"}
 },
 {
  "id":2,
  "stream":{"id":2,"title":"Stream","slug":"wilson"},
  "user":{"id":2,"username":"kunkka"}
 },
 {
  "id":3,
  "stream":{"id":3,"title":"Stream","slug":"doug"},
  "user":{"id":2,"username":"kunkka"}
 },
]
```

As you can see , all objects seem to have the same user attribute 'kunkka'(me) while in fact i would need the user object to belong/relate to their respective stream ids

This is the `FollowEntry.rb` file

```
class FollowEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stream

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :stream_id
end
```

And the `FollowEntrySerializer` file

```
class FollowEntrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :stream
  has_one :user
end
```

My FollowEntry schema

```
  create_table "follow_entries", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                       null: false
    t.integer  "stream_id",                     null: false
    t.index ["stream_id"], name: "index_follow_entries_on_stream_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_follow_entries_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Where is it going wrong?

**UPDATE** - i did a bit more debugging and this is the output in my console

```
  FollowEntry Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `follow_entries`.* FROM `follow_entries` WHERE `follow_entries`.`user_id` = 2
[active_model_serializers]   Stream Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `streams`.* FROM `streams` WHERE `streams`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Stream Load (17.9ms)  SELECT  `streams`.* FROM `streams` WHERE `streams`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

The `User Load` should actually filter by the result user.id column recieved from the previous Stream Load (in this case - it should be 1 and not 2) - Where do i change this?

Comment: `/users/{id}/following` means it will show that users following whose `id` you will pass in place of `{id}` and I guess in your case you are passing your id in that url

Comment: yea - i guess thats where the problem is. ideally , the app should get the user information from the stream table (got by the stream id) - how do i change that? I updated my question

Comment: I dont know all of your application structure so I guess Changing this involves many things like changing route, controller actions, database quries etc.